# Show Which JAR Depencency Contains A Particular Package or Class

Tags: maven, netbeans, netbeans-8

I'm using Netbeans to develop Maven projects and often I have found that I need to know which dependency JAR contains a particular package.

For example, if I am working on a project NOT originally created by myself and a particular class imports a package it would be nice to quickly be able to find which dependency JAR contains it, ideally highlighting it in the 'Projects' window under the 'Dependencies' branch.

Is there anyway to do this? Doing a straightforward search doesn't seem to be working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the menu: Navigate -> Go to type

Type in the name of the class or package and see the location of the containing jar in the location field in the bottom.

Comment: Thanks Peter. It's a little clunky way of doing it but it works!